# Deprecated Plus.PeopleApi.load

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin, google-people-api

Now that `Plus.API` is deprecated in [`Google Play Services 9.4`](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases), what is correct way to get *Google Plus circles* for authenticated user on Android Application?

Now We have deprecated method of loading plus users [Plus.PeopleApi.load](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/People.html#load(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.util.Collection%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))

New documentation says:

> If your app needs social information and more extensive profile data,
>   check out the Android Contacts Provider or the cross-platform People
>   API.

So I should go with *Android Contacts Provider* that seems to be a hard alternative (Because I have to filter contacts with cursors and also manage Runtime Permissions).

Any easy alternatives of *previous deprecated method* to just get List of G+ circles for user?

Comment: You were using the Plus API, now it's recommending the Contacts API *or* the provider

Comment: As I said in question above, I know that these solutions exist. But they are too hard alternatives of what is was before. 

I don't think that using cursors and managing Runtime Permissions is the alternative of simple method that is was.

Comment: Cursors are only for the Provider, yes? Not the [Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)

Comment: For read only access it still suggests me to use [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/)

Answer (score 4):

Google+ People API will eventually be fully deprecated 2017 Q1, see below deprecation notes for details:

Android announcement:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/api-deprecation

REST endpoint announcement:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve-a-collection-of-people

So you should consider alternatives suggested and not build new features based on G+ Circle friends, as **no data will be available for new users with the plus.login scope**.

If you don't want to request runtime permissions, you can still get signed-in user's contacts from [People REST API](https://developers.google.com/people/) (Note that this is something different from G+ People API). Also, if you need signed-in user's profile information other than first / last / display name, email and profile picture url (which is already provided by the Sign-in API), you should also use the same new People API.

On Android, when you need Contacts data (**In context, explaining to the user why you are asking for their contacts information. DO NOT request contacts scope upfront in your front-door Sign-In Activity**)

```
// Add dependencies (SDKs will be downloaded from mavenCentral)
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev4-1.22.0'
```

Then write sign-in code.

```
// Make sure your GoogleSignInOptions request email & contacts scopes as shown below
GoogleSignInOptions gso =
        new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(PeopleScopes.CONTACTS_READONLY)))
            .build();

// Follow official doc to sign-in.
// https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in
```

Then you can use new People Api to retrieve contacts list.

```
/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

// On worker thread
GoogleAccountCredential credential =
         GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(MainActivity.this, PeopleScopes.CONTACTS_READONLY);
credential.setSelectedAccount(
        new Account(googleSignInAccount.getEmail(), "com.google"));
People service = new People.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME /* whatever you like */) 
                .build();
ListConnectionsResponse response = service.people().connections()
        .list("people/me")
         // request 20 contacts
        .setPageSize(20)
        .execute();
List<Person> connections = response.getConnections();
if (connections != null && connections.size() > 0) {
    for (Person person : connections) {
        List<Name> names = person.getNames();
        if (names != null && names.size() > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Name: " + person.getNames().get(0).getDisplayName());
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No names available for connection.");
        }
        List<Gender> genders = person.getGenders();
        String ageRange = person.getAgeRange();
        List<Birthday> birthdays = person.getBirthdays();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Use GoogleSignInApi to getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient), and launch the intent; then in onActivityResult, you will be able to get GoogleSignInAccount. See this doc for details: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

Comment: Thanks Isabella, would you help me on this People API [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278457/android-google-people-api-error-tokenresponseexception-missing-parameter-code)  as well? Thanks alot !