# using Google new People Api ,How can i retrieve only people connections that are using my app (my app users only)

Tags: android, google-people-api, firebase-invites

I know i can use the People API to retrieve people connection

```
ListConnectionsResponse response = peopleService.people().connections().list("people/me").execute();
List<Person> connections = response.getConnections();
```

just as it is [explain here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743940/deprecated-plus-peopleapi-load)

But i would love to retrieve list of friends that uses my app only.
How can i retrieve only people connections that are  using my app (my app users only)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The [people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) API doesn't support such a feature. You will have to query all contacts of a user (with their permission of course) and check them against your existing userbase.

Comment: How can I query the contacts of a user?