# Android Google People API error: TokenResponseException: Missing parameter: code

Tags: android, google-api, google-people-api

I've used up my way. I followed the [tutorial](http://blog.grafixartist.com/people-api-android-tutorial-2/)(part 1 and 2) to use `Google People API` in my android project. It always hit an error saying `parameter code is missing` in the signed apk, and stucked at getting `GoogleTokenResponse`. It works fine in the debug version. What did I do wrong?

And I have done all these:

- Changed SHA1 to released version.
- Replace downloaded google-services.json file downloaded from Firebase.
- Client ID and Client Secret using OAuth Client ID for web
- Invalidate caches/Restart.
- Delete and recreate credential.

[image]

[image]

Google Sign In class:

```
public void Google_signIn() {

        //migrate to people api
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                // The serverClientId is an OAuth 2.0 web client ID
                .requestServerAuthCode(Constants.Google_Client_ID)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN),
                        new Scope(PeopleScopes.USERINFO_EMAIL))
                .build();

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
                    .enableAutoManage(activity /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
    }
```

Handler result after signing in successfully:

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
if (result.isSuccess()) {
            new PeoplesAsync().execute(result);
        }
```

PeoplesAsync:

```
class PeoplesAsync extends AsyncTask<GoogleSignInResult, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(GoogleSignInResult... params) {

            GoogleSignInAccount acct = params[0].getSignInAccount();
            JSONObject userInfo = new JSONObject();

            try {

                //basic profile information
                String G_id = acct.getId();
                String G_email = acct.getEmail();
                String G_name = acct.getDisplayName();
                String G_url = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();//profile img

                userInfo.put(AccountCenter.ACC_ID, G_id);
                userInfo.put(AccountCenter.ACC_NAME, G_name);
                userInfo.put(AccountCenter.ACC_EMAIL, G_email);
                userInfo.put(AccountCenter.ACC_PROFILE_IMAGE, G_url);

                //problem here
                //additional profile information
                com.google.api.services.people.v1.People peopleService = PeopleHelper.setUp(activity, acct.getServerAuthCode());

                com.google.api.services.people.v1.model.Person profile = peopleService.people().get("people/me")
                        .setRequestMaskIncludeField("person.genders,person.urls,person.birthdays").execute();

                if (!profile.isEmpty()) {

                    List<Url> urls = profile.getUrls();
                    List<Gender> genders = profile.getGenders();
                    List<Birthday> birthdays = profile.getBirthdays();

                    String G_link = urls.get(0).getValue();
                    String G_gender = genders.get(0).getValue();
                    Date bday = birthdays.get(0).getDate();
                    String G_birthday = String.format("%02d", bday.getDay()) + "-" + String.format("%02d", bday.getMonth()) + "-" + String.format("%04d", bday.getYear());// check: year will be 0000 if not shown, can be null ?

                    userInfo.put(AccountCenter.ACC_URL, G_link);
                    userInfo.put(AccountCenter.ACC_GENDER, G_gender);
                    userInfo.put(AccountCenter.ACC_BIRTHDAY, G_birthday);
                }

                AccountCenter.setUserInfo(activity, userInfo.toString(), Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE_GOOGLE);
                memberSocialLogin(activity, userInfo, Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE_GOOGLE, Constants.PROVIDER_NAME_GOOGLE);

            } catch (IOException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
                return ie.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }

            return "1";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);

            if (!response.equals("1")) {
                GeneralMethods.hideProgressDialog();

                if (mGoogleSignedInListener != null) {
                    mGoogleSignedInListener.onError(response);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

PeopleHelper:

```
public class PeopleHelper {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Grapps";//any name

    public static People setUp(final Context context, String serverAuthCode) {

        String progress = "0%";

        try {

            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

            // Redirect URL for web based applications.
            // Can be empty too.
            String redirectUrl = "";

            progress = "10%";

            //problem here
            // Exchange auth code for access token
            GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                    httpTransport,
                    jsonFactory,
                    Constants.Google_Client_ID,
                    Constants.Google_Client_Secret,
                    serverAuthCode,
                    redirectUrl).execute();

            progress = "40%";

            // Create a GoogleCredential object using the tokens from GoogleTokenResponse
            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setClientSecrets(Constants.Google_Client_ID, Constants.Google_Client_Secret)
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .build();

            progress = "60%";

            credential.setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);

            progress = "80%";

            // credential can then be used to access Google services
            return new People.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            final String finalProgress = progress + "\n" + e.toString();

            Handler handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    GeneralMethods.showAlert(context, "Error setting up People", finalProgress);
                }
            });

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there aren’t issues in Google Console and code, try look into Android project setting, set minifyEnabled false in build.gradle might help.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
//            minifyEnabled true
//            shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly! Don't know why but `minifyEnabled true` did block me from getting `GoogleTokenResponse` in signed apk, and my app works perfectly after setting it to false.